# Dynamic fields array in to single object mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am having mongo collection like below,

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("62aeb8301ed12a14a8873df1"),
   "Fields" : [ 
    {
        "FieldId" : "e8efd0b0-9d10-4584-bb11-5b24f189c03b",
        "Value" : [ 
            "test_123"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "FieldId" : "fa6745c2-b259-4a3b-8c6f-19eb78fbbbf5",
        "Value" : [ 
            "123"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "FieldId" : "2a1be5d0-8fb6-4b06-a253-55337bfe4bcd",
        "Value" : []
    }, 
    {
        "FieldId" : "eed12747-0923-4290-b09c-5a05107f5609",
        "Value" : [ 
            "234234234"
        ]
    },        
    {
        "FieldId" : "fe41d8fb-fa18-4fe5-b047-854403aa4d84",
        "Value" : [ 
            "Irrelevan"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "FieldId" : "93e46476-bf2e-44eb-ac73-134403220e9e",
        "Value" : [ 
            "test"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "FieldId" : "db434aca-8df3-4caf-bdd7-3ec23252c2c8",
        "Value" : [ 
            "2019-06-16T18:30:00.000Z"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "FieldId" : "00df903f-5d59-41c1-a3df-60eeafb77d10",
        "Value" : [ 
            "tewt"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "FieldId" : "e97d0386-cd42-6277-1207-e674c3268cec",
        "Value" : [ 
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "FieldId" : "35e55d27-7d2c-467d-8a88-09ad6c9f5631",
        "Value" : [ 
            "10"
        ]
    }
  ]
 }
```

This is all dynamic form fields.
So I  want to query and get result like to below object,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62aeb8301ed12a14a8873df1"),
    "e8efd0b0-9d10-4584-bb11-5b24f189c03b": ["test_123"],
    "fa6745c2-b259-4a3b-8c6f-19eb78fbbbf5": ["123"],
    "2a1be5d0-8fb6-4b06-a253-55337bfe4bcd": [],
    "eed12747-0923-4290-b09c-5a05107f5609": ["234234234"],
    "fe41d8fb-fa18-4fe5-b047-854403aa4d84": ["Irrelevan"],
    "93e46476-bf2e-44eb-ac73-134403220e9e":["test"],
    "db434aca-8df3-4caf-bdd7-3ec23252c2c8":["2019-06-16T18:30:00.000Z"],
    "00df903f-5d59-41c1-a3df-60eeafb77d10":["1"]
 }
```

I want final output like this combination of fields Fields.FieldID should be key and Fields.Value should be value here.

Please try to help to me to form the object like above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restructure your objects using [$arrayToObject](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/), then using that value to as a new root [$replaceRoot](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      // your query here
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      newRoot: {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          $map: {
            input: "$Fields",
            in: {
              k: "$$this.FieldId",
              v: "$$this.Value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$newRoot",
          {
            _id: "$_id"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IjotSt7JI7o)

Comment: Hi @Tom, Thanks for the reply it will really helpful for me. Can you please help me to achieve the below condition?

If Value array has 1 value then it should be direct value like 'Fields.FieldId':Field.Value 
If it has more than 1 value it is like now array.

Thanks in adavance!

Comment: `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62aeb8301ed12a14a8873df1"),
    "e8efd0b0-9d10-4584-bb11-5b24f189c03b": "test_123",
    "fa6745c2-b259-4a3b-8c6f-19eb78fbbbf5": "123",
    "2a1be5d0-8fb6-4b06-a253-55337bfe4bcd": null,
    "eed12747-0923-4290-b09c-5a05107f5609": "234234234",
    "fe41d8fb-fa18-4fe5-b047-854403aa4d84": ["Irrelevan","Cancel"],
    "db434aca-8df3-4caf-bdd7-3ec23252c2c8":"2019-06-16T18:30:00.000Z",
    "00df903f-5d59-41c1-a3df-60eeafb77d10":["1","2"]
 }`

Like this I need. If 1 value direct value, if more than 1 then it keeps remain array, Is this possible?

Comment: yea sure, you can use `$cond` to achieve this, https://mongoplayground.net/p/73XE82JjcAY

Comment: Hi @Tom, I have one more issue on this, It is returning error like below,

**"errmsg" : "The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: null"**

I think some times Value array may be null. Is there way to filter that also?

Comment: yep, you can just use `$isArray` to make sure it's an array.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/Iizs1Og83FL

Answer (score 0):

I try this and get result like you want

```
 db.collection.aggregate([{
    $replaceWith: {
      $mergeObjects: [
        {
          _id: "$_id"
        },
        {
          $arrayToObject: { $zip: {inputs: ["$Fields.FieldId","$Fields.Value"]}}
        }
      ]
    }
    }])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XGY2ghPtsY1)